# Ignited Datatables - display records on screen

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I'm using [Ignited Datatables](https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/) to display posts in tabular way in my view. I've been struggling the last 4 days in order to do this working correct, but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

This is the functionality that fetches the data

```
// the Post_model
/**
* Get page data on datatables
*/
public function get_datatable() {

    $this->load->library('datatables');

    $this->datatables->select('id, title, slug, sort_description, status');
    $this->datatables->from('posts');
    return $this->datatables->generate();
}

// the posts controller
/**
* List all posts
*/
public function index() {

    $this->data['datatables'] = true;

    $this->data['data_url'] = 'admin/posts/data_ajax';
    // $this->data['posts'] = $this->post_model->get_datatable();
    // dump($this->data['pages']);

    // load view
    $this->load->view('admin/posts/index', $this->data);
}


public function data_ajax() {
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false);
    echo $this->post_model->get_datatable();
    // echo json_encode($this->post_model->get_datatable());
    exit();
}

// the view
    <table class="table dataTable table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Url Slug</th>
         <th>Sort Description</th>
         <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Url Slug</th>
         <th>Sort Description</th>
         <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>

   <!-- <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="5" class="dataTables_empty"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody> -->
</table>

<?php if(isset($datatables)): ?>
    <?php echo js_tag('js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js'); ?>
    <?php echo js_tag('js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js'); ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.dataTable').DataTable({
                'bProcessing' : true,
                'bServerSide' : true,
                'sAjaxSource' : '<?php echo base_url($data_url); ?>',
                'sServerMethod' : 'POST',
                'fnServerData' : function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        dataType : 'json',
                        type : 'post', 
                        url : sSource,
                        data : aoData,
                        success : fnCallback,
                        "columns": [
                           { "data": "id" },
                           { "data": "title" },
                           { "data": "slug" },
                           { "data": "sort_description" },
                           { "data": "status" }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So if I access the `data_ajax()` function from the url like this
`localhost/my-blog/admin/posts/data_ajax`
and echo `echo $this->page->get_datatable();` I can the records

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[{"id":"1","title":"First post","slug":"first-post","sort_description":"This is the first post","status":"visible"},{"id":"2","title":"Second post","slug":"second-post","sort_description":"This is the second post","status":"visible"}]}
```

but the problem is I can't display them on my screen. In addition I also get this warning in an alert box

`DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4`

This is a screenshot of what I get
[image]

How can I make this work properly? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: check no of columns in coming in query response  from query and html tables

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand you. Could you explain more thoroughly please ??

Comment: your json response having 5 columns and html table having 6 columns 
make them correct to get view display

Comment: I did it but still getting the same worning and can't display records. Please review

Comment: try this   $('.dataTable').dataTable()

Comment: same thing, no luck ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

> Add Columns parameter to associate data with column

The code will be something like this

```
$('.dataTable').DataTable({
   'bProcessing' : true,
   'bServerSide' : true,
   'sAjaxSource' : '<?php echo base_url($data_url); ?>',
   'sServerMethod' : 'POST',
   "columns": [
           { "data": "id" },
           { "data": "title" },
           { "data": "slug" },
           { "data": "date_published" },
           { "data": "status" }
        ]
   'fnServerData' : function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
      $.ajax({
          dataType : 'json',
          type : 'post', 
          url : sSource,
          data : aoData,
          success : fnCallback,
     });
  }
});
```

Please refer [datatables column](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data), for details

Comment: what do you mean by `refer [datatables column][1], for details` ??

Comment: It is link to datatables columns parameter, some editing issues was there, corrected now. Hope it will help.

Comment: still no luck.. I still get the warning and also can't display the records.. I'm going to update the code to review and give you a screen shot too

Comment: use columns option in datatables not in ajax. Code edited. Please check.

Comment: One additional thing: how can I make the collumns dynamic ?

Comment: The columns should be associated with data columns, to display data in specified columns

Comment: I can display results now, but I can't, sort them or work the search functionality, or show more than 10 records

Comment: It seems not working properly.. I can now see more than 10 records by default, and also the rest of the functionality doesn't seem to work (pagination, show more records, search and sorting cols)

Comment: Please refer, [datatables options](https://www.datatables.net/reference/option/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90418/discussion-between-lykos-and-ravneet).

Comment: how add link to values in a column?

Comment: You can edit data, using this, "data": function ( row, type, val, meta ) { return "<a href=edit-link'+row.id+'>"+ Link +"</a>" }. row will give all the data of that specific row.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. This is how I got it solved:
You have to set the columns as this

```
"columns": [null, null, null, null, null,{}]
```

Set it separately not in the Ajax.